# Length of user-defined string literal as a template argument?

Tags: c++11, generic-programming, user-defined-literals

Is there any way to get behavior like this?

```
// Some definition(s) of operator "" _my_str
// Some definition of function or macro MY_STR_LEN

using T1 = MY_STR_LEN("ape"_my_str);
// T1 is std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 3U>.

using T2 = MY_STR_LEN("aardvark"_my_str);
// T2 is std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 8U>.
```

It seems not, since the string literals are passed immediately to `some_return_type operator "" _my_str(const char*, std::size_t);` and never to a literal operator template (2.14.8/5).  That size function parameter can't be used as a template argument, even though it will almost always be a constant expression.

But it seems like there ought to be some way to do this.

---

Update: The accepted answer, that this is not possible without an extra definition per literal, is accurate for C++11 as asked, and also C++14 and C++17. C++20 allows the exact result asked for:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <type_traits>
#include <string_view>

struct cexpr_str {
    const char* ptr;
    std::size_t len;

    template <std::size_t Len>
    constexpr cexpr_str(const char (&str)[Len]) noexcept
    : ptr(str), len(Len) {}
};

// Essentially the same as
// std::literals::string_view_literals::operator""sv :
template <cexpr_str Str>
constexpr std::string_view operator "" _my_str () noexcept
{
     return std::string_view(Str.ptr, Str.len);
}

#define MY_STR_LEN(sv) \
  std::integral_constant<std::size_t, (sv).size()>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reading C++11 2.14.8 carefully reveals that the "literal operator template" is only considered for numeric literals, but *not* for string and character literals.

However, the following approach seems to give you constexpr access to the string length (but not the pointer):

```
struct MyStr
{
    char const * str;
    unsigned int len;
    constexpr MyStr(char const * p, unsigned int n) : str(p), len(n) {}
};

constexpr MyStr operator "" _xyz (char const * s, unsigned int len)
{
    return MyStr(s, len);
}

constexpr auto s = "Hello"_xyz;
```

Test:

```
#include <array>

using atype = std::array<int, s.len>; // OK
```

Comment: Yes, but that's just for the one particular object `s`.  So we need a name for every user-defined literal?

Comment: I can't work out `myTemplate<len_here> operator"" _test(char const * s, unsigned int len)` either.

Comment: @MooingDuck: how do you mean? As I said, for string literals, the length is only available as a dynamic parameter, not as a constant expression, so I don't think you can parameterize a template on the length...